# when does a sub stop in perl regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, perl

I'm trying to translate some perl code into python and I ran into some problem with a certain regex I just can't figure out what it does or why does it stop

**this is the regex**

```
$url =~ s/^.*\///;
```

now I've tried to pass some urls and see what comes out

so this is what comes out

```
# string input
"http://perltest.my-mobile.org/c/test.cgi?u=USER&p=PASS"

# string output
"test.cgi?u=USER&p=PASS"
```

I really don't know why it is stopping at `test` as far as I understand it,
it replaces any character in the beginning of the string with nothing 
so why does it stop at test?

And if you can help me write a regex in python that does the same thing 
that would be cool

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's stopping at the last `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I really don't know why it is stopping at 'test' as far as I understand it, it replaces any character in the beginning of the string with nothing so why does it stop at test?

Because of the `\/` being part of the pattern.

```
#            V here
$url =~ s/^.*\///;
```

It would be clearer if the code was using a different quoting delimiter, which is possible in Perl. That way, there would not be the [*leaning toothpick syndrome*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) here.

```
$url =~ s{^.*/}{};
```

Note that it's greedy by default, so it will gobble up all the slashes until the last one.

You can use the [`re` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode) in debug mode to learn more about what the regex engine does under the hood.

```
use re 'debug';

my $url = "http://perltest.my-mobile.org/c/test.cgi?u=USER&p=PASS";

$url =~ s{^.*/}{};
```

This will output to STDERR.

```
Compiling REx "^.*/"
Final program:
   1: SBOL /^/ (2)
   2: STAR (4)
   3:   REG_ANY (0)
   4: EXACT </> (6)
   6: END (0)
floating "/" at 0..9223372036854775807 (checking floating) anchored(SBOL) minlen 1 
Matching REx "^.*/" against "http://perltest.my-mobile.org/c/test.cgi?u=USER&p=PASS"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [0..54] gave 5
  Found floating substr "/" at offset 5 (rx_origin now 0)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 0
   0 <> <http://per>         |   0| 1:SBOL /^/(2)
   0 <> <http://per>         |   0| 2:STAR(4)
                             |   0| REG_ANY can match 54 times out of 2147483647...
  31 <org/c> </test.cgi?>    |   1|  4:EXACT </>(6)
  32 <rg/c/> <test.cgi?u>    |   1|  6:END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "^.*/"
```

Comment: *I'm trying to translate some perl code into python... and if you can help me write a regex in python that does the same thing that would be cool* - OP does not need a Perl solution. Actually, it is a code conversion request.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and I am not giving one. They didn't ask how to translate it. They asked why it is doing what it does. I'm explaining that, in detail. And I was already done writing my answer when the OP edited in that last request you are quoting.